# PHP regular expression to match multiple email ID formats

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to obtain the local part of an email ID using regex.
The challenge here is that the local part comes in two different formats and I need to figure out which format I'm reading and prepare the alternate form of that email ID. As always the snippet of my code that does this is pasted below.

```
$testarray = array("user1@gmail.com", "user2.tp@gmail.com", "user3@gmail.com", "user4.tp@gmail.com", "user5.tp@gmail.com");

foreach($testarray as $emailID) {
  preg_match("/([\w\d]*)\.([\w\d]*)@gmail.com/", $emailID, $match);

  if ($match[2] == "tp") {
    $altform = $match[1] . "@gmail.com";
  } else {
    $altform = $match[1] . ".tp@gmail.com";
  }

  error_log("ALTERNATE FORM OF $emailID IS $altform");

}
```

The problem I'm facing here is I'm not getting the desired result as neither `$match[1]` and `$match[2]` match anything for `"user1@gmail.com"`.

Comment: Please share the desired result

Comment: Your regular expression is expecting a full stop `\.` character, you should test if `preg_match()` actually worked or not before trying to consume `$match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an optional group around the dot + word chars subpattern, and then check if the group matched after executing the search:

```
foreach($testarray as $emailID) {
    $altform = "";
    if (preg_match("/(\w+)(?:\.(\w+))?@gmail\.com/", $emailID, $match))
    {
        if (!empty($match[2]) && $match[2] == "tp") {
            $altform = $match[1] . "@gmail.com";
        } else {
            $altform = $match[1] . ".tp@gmail.com";
        }
    }
    print_r("ALTERNATE FORM OF $emailID IS $altform\n");
}
```

See the [online PHP demo](https://ideone.com/gZrLS4).

**Notes on the pattern**:

- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more word chars
- `(?:\.(\w+))?` - 1 or 0 occurrences (due to `?` quantifier) of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `(\w+)` - Capturing group 2: one or more word chars
- `@gmail\.com` - a literal string `@gmail.com` (note the `.` is escaped to match a literal dot).